# Problem when run a bytecode llvm (.bc) with lli (JIT)

Tags: haskell, llvm

I compiled my haskell sources in `.ll` files with the GHC. Then I generated several `.bc` (bytecode), using the `llvm-as` command.

After that I link everything in a single `.bc` using the `llvm-link` command. Then optimized with the opt command.

The final result was trying to execute with `lli` command (JIT), but the following error occurred:

> 'main' function not found in module.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Good. What am I doing? I'm trying to compile a yesod project on NixOS.

I used first:

```
$ stack --nix-packages llvm_39 build --ghc-options = "-fllvm -keep-llvm-files"
```

This generated `.ll` corresponding to the sources. So I got those `.ll` and copied in another directory. Next I used `llvm-as` to compile to bytecod each one of them:

```
$ llvm-as <filename>
```

Then I put it all together into one file. What I have in the yesod project is how you know: a main:

```
import Prelude (IO)
import Application (appMain)

main :: IO ()
main = appMain
```

I thought that after putting everything together in a .bc I could run with `lli` as it is possible to do when an .exe is generated. With yesod just the `.exe`, config folder and static folder in the same place and cabum!

The yesod project was generated with the postgre template and I have not even programmed it yet. I am testing the build.

In time.

Files:

```
Application.ll
Common.ll
Foundation.ll
Import.ll
Model.ll
Paths_TesteYesod.ll
Settings.ll
Comment.ll
DevelMain.ll
Home.ll
main.ll
NoFoundation.ll
Profile.ll
StaticFiles.ll
```

I used llvm-link on all to get a TestYesod.bc

Comment: Just to be sure -- you do have a `Main` module with a `main :: IO ()` function defined in it, right?

Comment: This would be an easier question to answer if we had an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Could you update your question to include a minimal, complete, and verifiable example?

Comment: It's difficult for me to post an MCVE. It is not a problem that occurred in any particular snippet of code. As I said all the code that the project contains is of the yesod scaffolding. When I compile with 'stack build' and then I use 'stack exec - yesod devel' everything works normally.

My problem is how to do a certain type of build. Has anyone ever tried to compile a yesod project to bytecode llvm and try to run as llvm JIT?

Comment: MCVE: Put `main :: IO (); main = return ()` in a `Main.hs`, `ghc -fllvm -keep-llvm-files Main.hs`, then `lli Main.ll`. This is a linker/compiler-level error, which means the code doesn't matter, the libraries mostly don't, and the only things that really do are the compilation steps. My guess as to the cause of this problem is that GHC simply doesn't write a `main` function. Rather, `main` might be in the RTS (which is linked in), where it can set up GC, read RTS options, etc., and eventually that calls into `Main.main`. This may be a showstopper if `lli` can't link the RTS.

Comment: Thank you HTNW. Sorry I did not provide an MCVE. But when I hit my eye on it, I thought

"should be a linker problem and it is a difficult problem. It's best to look for someone you've tried and know".

I think you said it right. The main must be in the RTS. In this case I will give up doing because it will require a manual solution that will require a lot of time.